# Single Selection in Html.ListBox()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I have a Scenerio to Select single value from the list box, it is possible to disable multiple selection

```
Html.ListBox("Employees",ViewData["Employees"] as SelectList)
```

2ndly how to show the results back on edit???????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a Scenerio to Select single value from the list box, it is
>   possible to disable multiple selection

Use a DropDownList instead of ListBox if you want single selection.

Comment: Dear I wana have similarity, I have two ListBoxes one to select Manager(Single) and one to select from Remaining Employees(Multiple)

Comment: Thanks, I think insisting this would be a rigidity